# Looking for LSTM / GRU Implementation

Tags: lstm

Some years ago I did a lot of work with "normal" neural networks and supervised learning via backpropagation. And I know how to implement a standard neural network.

Now I want to learn the basics of LSTM / GRU networks, but all I can find are abstract formulas or how to use Keras, TensorFlow or other frameworks. I know that these frameworks are well optimized for speed, but that's not what I'm interested in, because I can't see, what happens inside these frameworks. I'm interested in a simple implementation in plain e.g. Java/C#/VB or whatever, without using a RNN framework to understand how these RNNs work. A simple demo app with a supervised learning to see how all the weights inside are been set would be great. I googled the last two weeks for details, but it seems as if I'm unable to choose the right keywords.

Any programming language appreciated, even FORTRAN or COBOL :-)

Comment: Finally I found a very clear implementation in JavaScript here https://cs.stanford.edu/people/karpathy/recurrentjs/

Comment: I just got an email, showing me this explaining video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9zhrxE5PQgY

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest you have a look at the stanford course CS231n. The lectures and assignments are at http://cs231n.github.io . You can find course videos on YouTube. The course includes a project to use RNN to generate a description of an image.

A deep learning framework has low level APIs and high level APIs. If your target is only learn the implementation of LSTM or GRU, you can use the low level API of deep learning framework to build a LSTM network by yourself. A framework gives you the functionality of tensor operation and auto gradient, which you may have already known how to implement.

Here I take pytorch as example. You can have a look at the source code of the LSTM implementation in pytorch https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/master/torch/nn/modules/rnn.py . Don't be afraid to read the source code. This implementation has only 100 lines of useful code. Hopefully it will help you get some idea about the LSTM / GRU network.